# how to get not equal to in python dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

df_price_unlockeditems is a dataframe of objects that has some columns. below is the condition where lIQSPricingStatus = 0 and lIQSRevReq =2 filter those elements.

df_quickshipped_approved = df_price_unlockeditems[(df_price_unlockeditems['lIQSPricingStatus'] == 0) & (df_price_unlockeditems['lIQSRevReq'] == 2)]

Need to find the objects not falling in these 2 conditions.
basically **not in** df_price_unlockeditems['lIQSPricingStatus'] == 0) & (df_price_unlockeditems['lIQSRevReq'] == 2)

Please help me here

Comment: For Pandas questions especially, it can help to get a better answer by providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce your data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

pandas.DataFrame.ne can you help maybe.

Check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html#pandas.DataFrame.ne) in the pandas documentation ( see also the notes for more possibilities.